# Conditional Statement checking length of string

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a conditional statement that returns to me "nothing entered" if the string length is less than 1. However, I'm getting an error message in xcode that says: Expected identifier. I think my syntax may be wrong but I can't figure it out.

```
- (IBAction)batman:(id)sender {
if ([self.nameTextField.text.length] < 1)
{   //returnType method argument
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nothing entered."];
}
else {
    self.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Batman %@", self.nameTextField.text ];
}
```

}

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, so this question will be 'closed'.

Comment: Welcome. It would be helpful to find yourself a good Objective-C tutorial. It's important to learn the language before you try to write an iOS app. The time spent now will save you a ton of time later.

Comment: @Hannes thanks! Just closed it.

Comment: @rmaddy great suggestion. I'm going through code school's objective-c tutorial currently? Any others you would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of your brackets `[]` and it should work:

```
- (IBAction)batman:(id)sender {
    if (self.nameTextField.text.length < 1) {
        self.secondLabel.text = @"nothing entered.";
    } else {
        self.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Batman %@", self.nameTextField.text ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use `([self.nameTextField.text length] < 1)`.  Or `([[self.nameTextField] text] length < 1)`.  Or `([[[self nameTextField] text] length] < 1)`.  Or one of several other permutations.

Comment: @user3255585 You couldn't use the brackets because you were redundantly adding a bracket pair around dot notation, which is the same thing as doing [[receiver message]]

Comment: Consider localization as well. Please see yet another bit of awesome from Mattt : http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/